# In es6+ isFinite([]) is different to isFinite({})

Tags: javascript, object

I am interested in why passing an empty Object initialiser to  isFinite results in False. While passing an empty Array results in True? Is it logical for them both to result in a different thing?

Tldr:
isFinite([]);   // true
isFinite({});  // false
Why not both true? Why not both false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an object is converted to a number, it results in `NaN`, because when an object is converted to a primitive, you get `[object Object]`, which cannot be converted to a number.

```js
console.log(Number({}));
```

When an array is converted to a number, if the array is empty, it results in `0` (because when an array is converted to a primitive, all elements are joined by a comma, like `.join(',')`; an empty array results in the empty string, which gets coerced to 0).

```js
console.log(Number([]));
```

`NaN` is not considered as finite:

> false if the argument is positive or negative Infinity or NaN or undefined; otherwise, true.

So `isFinite([])` resolves to `isFinite(0)`, and `isFinite({})` results in `isFinite(NaN)`.

Answer (score 1):

Type coersion.

```
+[] // 0
+{} // NaN
```

Hence the difference is actually between `isFinite(0)` and `isFinite(NaN)`